# Does Python have an equivalent to java.lang.Math.nextUp?

Tags: python, floating-point

I have a Python `float`, and I want to have the `float`s which are 1 [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) greater and lesser.

In Java, I would do this with [`Math.nextUp(x)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp%28double%29) and [`Math.nextAfter(x, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextAfter%28double,%20double%29).

Is there a way to do this in Python?  I thought about implementing it myself with [`math.frexp` and `math.ldexp`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html) but as far as I know Python doesn't specify the size of floating point types.

Comment: Same question was asked here: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/739926-next-float, with good answers...

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** In Python 3.9+ there is [`math.nextafter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nextafter):

```py
>>> import math
>>> x = 4
>>> math.nextafter(x, math.inf)
4.000000000000001
```

---

<sup>Old answer:</sup>

You could look at how [`Decimal.next_plus()`/`Decimal.next_minus()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fecf9e6d7630/Lib/decimal.py#l3448) are implemented:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> d = D.from_float(123456.78901234567890)
>>> d
Decimal('123456.789012345674564130604267120361328125')
>>> d.next_plus()
Decimal('123456.7890123456745641306043')
>>> d.next_minus()
Decimal('123456.7890123456745641306042')
>>> d.next_toward(D('-inf'))
Decimal('123456.7890123456745641306042')
```

Make sure that [decimal context](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context) has values that you need:

```
>>> from decimal import getcontext
>>> getcontext()
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999999, Emax=999999999,
capitals=1, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])
```

---

Alternatives:

- Call [C99 `nextafter()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163157/4279) using `ctypes`:

  ```
    >>> import ctypes
    >>> nextafter = ctypes.CDLL(None).nextafter
    >>> nextafter.argtypes = ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double
    >>> nextafter.restype = ctypes.c_double
    >>> nextafter(4, float('+inf'))
    4.000000000000001
    >>> _.as_integer_ratio()
    (4503599627370497, 1125899906842624)
  ```

  Using `numpy`:

  ```
    >>> import numpy
    >>> numpy.nextafter(4, float('+inf'))
    4.0000000000000009
    >>> _.as_integer_ratio()
    (4503599627370497, 1125899906842624)
  ```

  Despite different `repr()`, the result is the same.
- If we ignore edge cases then a simple frexp/ldexp solution from [@S.Lott answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6064066/4279) works:

  ```
    >>> import math, sys
    >>> m, e = math.frexp(4.0)
    >>> math.ldexp(2 * m + sys.float_info.epsilon, e - 1)
    4.000000000000001
    >>> _.as_integer_ratio()
    (4503599627370497, 1125899906842624)
  ```
- [pure Python `next_after(x, y)`  implementation by @Mark Dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10426033/4279) that takes into account edge cases. The result is the same in this case.

Comment: It looks good by need some polish - since float in python has 53 bits for mantissa http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. I think better is use frexp ldexp - can be faster.

Comment: @Chameleon: yes. You can use `frexp()`/`ldexpr()` to find the "next after".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but `sys.float_info.epsilon` is the "difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable as a float", and you could do `x * (1 + sys.float_info.epsilon)`.

http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.float_info

Comment: It's a related idea, but not exactly what I want.  Essentially it is correct for an exponent of 0, but for smaller exponents it is too large, and for larger it is too small.  Thank you for pointing out `sys.float_info`.  At least with this structure I can reliably determine the size of the underlying floating point type, even if I still have to guess that it's IEEE-754.  With this I can work out a solution along the lines of @Benjamin's suggestions, specifically with the struct module.

Comment: `x + epsilon`? wouldn't that be rather `x * (1 + epsilon)`?

Comment: @vartec I don't know, but I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: @rlibby: to take into account the exponent: [`next_after_x = (m+sys.float_info.epsilon)*2**e` where `m, e = math.frexp(x)` from @S.Lott's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6064066/4279)

Comment: or closer to `nextafter(x, float('+inf'))` value: `((2*m+sys.float_info.epsilon)*2**(e-1))` because `.5 <= m < 1`.