# How can I print many significant figures in Python?

Tags: python

For a scientific application I need to output very precise numbers, so I have to print 15 significant figures. There are already questions on this topic here, but they all concern with *truncating* the digits, not *printing more*.

I realized that the `print` function converts the input `float` to a 10 character `string`. Also, I became aware of the `decimal` module, but that does not suit my needs.

So the question is, how can I easily print a variable amount of signifcant figures of my floats, where I need to display more than 10?

Comment: Keep in mind that a `float` might not actually be capable of representing the values you're using to the precision you require, which means that your calculations could very well be horribly wrong.

Comment: @Wooble [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163157/566644) very nice answer delves into the question you're raising. It's worth a look.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the string formatting operator `%`:

```
In [3]: val = 1./3

In [4]: print('%.15f' % val)
0.333333333333333
```

or `str.format()`:

```
In [8]: print(str.format('{0:.15f}', val))
Out[8]: '0.333333333333333'
```

In new code, the latter is the preferred style, although the former is still widely used.

For more info, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: `print('{0:.15f}'.format(val))` is also another way to do it in the new format.

Comment: Note that this does not print 15 _significant_ digits, but just 15 digits after the decimal point. For very large or very small numbers, this does not make much sense. IMHO, using `"%.15e"` might be more reasonable.

Comment: Yeah, this is decimal places not significant figures.

Answer (score 60):

Let:

```
>>> num = 0.0012345
```

For up to *3 [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)*:

```
>>> f'{num:.3}'
'0.00123'
```

For *3 [decimal places](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decimal_place)*:

```
>>> f'{num:.3f}'
'0.001'
```

See the "presentation types for floating point and decimal" table at the bottom of [this section](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for any additional requirements provided by `e, E, f, F, g, G, n, %, None`.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

Comment: This displays numbers in scientific format, e.g. 12.0 => "1.2e+01", which may not be what people expect.

Comment: @quantoid According to my REPL, `f'{12.0:.3}' == '12.0'`. But it seems you're correct when `abs(float(f'{num:.3}')) >= 10**2`. It's not totally unreasonable behavior either... for instance, how would you handle `1234.56`? Printing either `1230` | `1230.` is misleading because `not a float` | `0 is actually 4`. Printing `1.23e4` seems the only reasonable solution here.

Comment: In any case, I think most people want to print numbers s.t. `abs(float(f'{num:.{d}}')) < 10**d`

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be deleted. `f"{4.2:.3}"` produced `4.2`, which is not three significant figures.

Answer (score 11):

Thought the original question wanted to format n significant figures, not n decimal points.  So a custom function might be required until some more native built-in types are on offer?
So you'll want something like:

```
def float_nsf(q,n):
    """
    Truncate a float to n significant figures.  May produce overflow in 
    very last decimal place when q < 1.  This can be removed by an extra 
    formatted print. 
    Arguments:
      q : a float
      n : desired number of significant figures
    Returns:
    Float with only n s.f. and trailing zeros, but with a possible small overflow.
    """
    sgn=np.sign(q)
    q=abs(q)
    n=int(np.log10(q/10.)) # Here you overwrite input n!
    if q<1. :
        val=q/(10**(n-1))
        return sgn*int(val)*10.**(n-1)
    else:
        val=q/(10**n)
        return sgn*int(val)*10.**n
```

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be deleted. `float_nsf(4.2,3)` produced `4.0`, which is neither the correct answer nor three significant figures.

Answer (score 10):

To display N significant figures (not decimal places) you use the "g" format:

```
>>> x = 1.23
>>> print("%.2g" % x)
1.2
>>> x = 12.3
>>> print("%.2g" % x)
12
```

See [format spec](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for details on precision:

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be
>   displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted
>   with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating
>   point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'. For non-number types the field
>   indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters
>   will be used from the field content. The precision is not allowed for
>   integer values.

Comment: The docs on `g`: The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted with presentation type `'e'` and precision `p-1` would have exponent exp. Then if `-4 <= exp < p`, the number is formatted with presentation type `'f'` and precision `p-1`-exp. Otherwise, the number is formatted with presentation type `'e'` and precision `p-1`. In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it, unless the `'#'` option is used.

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be deleted. `f"{4.2:.3g}"` produced `4.2`, which is not three significant figures.

Answer (score 3):

Use these two common print idioms for formatting. Its a matter of personal taste on which is better.

```
value = 10/3            #gives a float of 3.33333.....

print '%.15f' % value
print str.format('{0:.15f}', value)
```

Personally I think the first is more compact and the 2nd is more explicit. Format has more features when working with multiple vals.

Comment: I downvoted because this gives 15 digits after the decimal point, not 15 [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).
I deem [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52899472/2980080) to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

All existing answers are wrong.

Here is one that works for all cases that I've tried:

```py
import numpy as np
def float_to_nsf(f: float, n: int) -> str:
  """Convert a float into a string with a chosen number of significant figures. 
     The decimal point is always included, even if trailing."""
  s = np.format_float_positional(f, fractional=False, min_digits=n, precision=n)
  if s[0:2] == "0.":
    s = "0." + f"{s[2:]:0<{n}}"
  return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function I wrote, it seems to be working fine and it's quite **simple**!:

```
def nsf(num, n=1):
    """n-Significant Figures"""
    numstr = ("{0:.%ie}" % (n-1)).format(num)
    return float(numstr)
```

1. It first converts the number to a string using **exponent notation**
2. Then returns it as **float**.

Some tests:

```
>>> a = 2./3
>>> b = 1./3
>>> c = 3141592
>>> print(nsf(a))
0.7
>>> print(nsf(a, 3))
0.667
>>> print(nsf(-a, 3))
-0.667
>>> print(nsf(b, 4))
0.3333
>>> print(nsf(-b, 2))
-0.33
>>> print(nsf(c, 5))
3141600.0
>>> print(nsf(-c, 6))
-3141590.0
```

I hope this helps you ;)

Comment: Hmm, this kept spitting out numbers in exponent notation. Perhaps because I converted them to back to strings later?, i.e. str(float(...))

Comment: This answer is wrong and should be deleted. `nsf(4.2,3)` produced `4.2`, which is not three significant figures.

Comment: @Myridium, please note that 4.2 only has 2 significant figures, the trailing zeroes are irrelevant.
You may find the definition of significant figures here: 
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: In any case, I believe the solution provided by @MateenUlhaq is much better, i.e.: ```'{:.3}'.format(4.2)``` will output ```'4.2'```

Comment: @ionelberdin that is incorrect. I.e. from the article you linked: *"Zeros to the right of the last non-zero digit (trailing zeros) in a number with the decimal point are significant"*. The number `4.2` to three significant figures is `4.20`.