# Formatting integers and floats inside strings in python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to figure out how to print formatted strings rounding to significant figures. Say I have:

```
x = 8829834.123
```

And I want to print it rounded to four sig figs, as an integer.
I tried:

```
print "%4d"%x
```

and I just get:

```
8829834
```

Why won't it display:

```
8829000?
```

I thought that was how string formatting worked.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348825/how-to-round-integers-in-python.
You could consider the use of round() as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415939/how-can-i-print-many-significant-figures-in-python

Answer (score 4):

To round to 4 significant digits:

```
f = float("%.4g" % 8829834.123)
```

To print it as an integer:

```
print "%.0f" % f
# -> 8830000
```

Answer (score 2):

Format Specifier does not support integer rounding, there may be some solutions but not out of the Box, here are couple of them

```
>>> print "{:d}000".format(int(x/1000))
8829000
>>> print "{:d}".format(int(round(x,-3)))
8830000
```

Comment: It won't produce result rounded to 4 significant digits if `x` has different order of magnitude e.g., `123456789`