# Python arithmetic with small numbers

Tags: python, numerical

I am getting the following unexpected result when I do arithmetic with small numbers in Python:

```
>>> sys.float_info
sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
>>> (1. - (1.e-17) ) < 1.
False
```

I know that floating point numbers do not have infinite precision, but it should be able to handle "large" small numbers like 1e-17, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 14):

The precision of floats is higher near 0 than it is near 1.

- There are 4591870180066957722 floats between 0.0 and 0.1.
- There are 900719925474099 floats between 0.9 and 1.0, fewer by far.

Float density halves at regular intervals, it looks something like this:

[image: visualization of density of floats]

Here is the next float after `1.`, in the direction of `0.`:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.nextafter(1., 0.)
0.9999999999999999
>>> format(math.nextafter(1., 0.), ".32f")  # let's see more decimal places
'0.99999999999999988897769753748435'
```

The mathematically correct value of *1 - 10<sup>-17</sup>* is *0.99999999999999999* (there are seventeen nines), I'll call this number *n*. Like almost all numbers, *n* can't be represented exactly with a float.

```
0.99999999999999999                    # n
0.00000000000000001                    # distance between n and 1, i.e. 10^-17
0.00000000000000010102230246251565...  # distance between n and nextafter(1., 0.)
```

So you see, *1 - 10<sup>-17</sup>* is about 10 times further from `nextafter(1., 0.)` than it is from `1.`. When the expression `1. - 1.e-17` is evaluated by the interpreter it gives you back the closest possible result, which is `1.` exactly. It wouldn't make sense to return any other float, that would be even further away from the "real" result (pardon the pun).

*Note:* [`math.nextafter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nextafter) is available in Python 3.9+. In earlier versions you can use `numpy.nextafter` similarly.

Related question -> [Increment a Python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out numpy.nextafter() and explaining how to use it! This is extremely useful for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

First, let's review what `epsilon` really is in the return value of `sys.float_info`.

[Epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) (or ) is the smallest number such that    **0.5 +  ≠ 0.5 AND 0.5 -  ≠ 0.5**

Python is telling you that the smallest number that will cause `0.5` to increment or decrement repeatably is `epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16` -- **but this is only for the value 0.5**.  You are attempting to increment `1.0` by `1.0e-17`. This is a larger value (1.0 vs 0.5) being incremented by a smaller number than the  for 0.5 (1.0e-17 vs 2.2e-16). You are off by an order of magnitude roughly, since the increment value of 1.0e-17 is an order of magnitude smaller than the relative epsilon for 1.0.

You can see this here:

These change the value of `0.5`

```
>>> 0.5+sys.float_info.epsilon
0.5000000000000002
>>> 0.5-sys.float_info.epsilon
0.4999999999999998
```

These values do not:

```
>>> 0.5+sys.float_info.epsilon/10.0
0.5
>>> 0.5-sys.float_info.epsilon/10.0
0.5
>>> 5.0+sys.float_info.epsilon
5.0
>>> 5.0-sys.float_info.epsilon
5.0
```

**Explanation:**

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) defines the floating point format in use today on most standard computers (specialty computers or libraries may use a different format.) The [64 bit format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) of IEEE 754 uses 53 bits of precision to calculate and 52 to store to the mantissa of a floating point value. Since you have a fixed 52/53 bits to work with, the magnitude and accuracy of the mantissa changes for larger / smaller values. So then the  changes as the relative magnitude of a floating point number changes. The value of  for 0.5 is different that the value for 1.0 and for 100.0.

For a variety of very good and platform-specific reasons (storage and representation, rounding, etc), even though you *could* use a smaller number, epsilon is defined as using 52 bits of precision for the 64 bit float format. Since most Python implementations use a C double float for float, this can be demonstrated:

```
>>> 2**-52==sys.float_info.epsilon
True
```

See how many bits *your* platform will do:

```
>>> 0.5 + 2.0**-53
0.5000000000000001
>>> 0.5 - 2.0**-53
0.4999999999999999
>>> 0.5 + 2.0**-54
0.5                           # fail for 0.5 + 54 bits...
>>> 0.5 - 2.0**-54
0.49999999999999994           # OK for minus
>>> 0.5 - 2.0**-55
0.5                           # fail  for 0.5 minus 55 bits...
```

There are several work arounds for your issue:

1. You can use the C99 concept of [nextafter](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/nextafter.3.html) to calculate the value appropriate epsilon. For Python, either use numpy or the Decimal class to calculate `nextafter`. More on `nextafter` in my previous answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163157/648852)
2. Use integers. A 64 bit integer will clearly handle an epsilon value in the 17th order of magnitude without rounding.
3. Use an arbitrary precision math library. [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) is in the standard Python distribution.

The important concept is that the value of  is **relative to value** (and if you are incrementing or decrementing).

This can be seen here:

```
>>> numpy.nextafter(0.0,1.0)-0.0
4.9406564584124654e-324                 # a relative epsilon value of 4.94e-324
>>> numpy.nextafter(0.01,1.0)-0.01
1.7347234759768071e-18                  # 1e-17 would still work...
>>> numpy.nextafter(0.1,1.0)-0.1
1.3877787807814457e-17                  # 1e-17 would >>barely<< work...
>>> numpy.nextafter(0.5,1.0)-0.5
1.1102230246251565e-16                  # a relative epsilon value of 1.1e-16
>>> numpy.nextafter(500.0,501.0)-500.0
5.6843418860808015e-14                  # relative epsilon of 5.6e-14
>>> numpy.nextafter(1e17,1e18)-1e17
16.0                                    # the other end of the spectrum...
```

So you can see that 1e-17 will work handily to increment values between 0.0 and 0.1 but not many values greater than that. As you can see above, the relative  for 1e17 is 16.

Comment: +1 -- great answer. Since `math.ldexp(x,i)` is the same as `x * (2**i)` your examples would be clearer with `2.0**-52` vs `math.ldexp(1.0, -52)` Just sayin'...

Answer (score 3):

> it should be able to handle "large" small numbers like 1e-17, shouldn't it?

Not necessarily (it depends on the numbers). A `float` cannot exactly represent either `1e-17` or `1-(1e-17)`. In the case of the latter, the nearest number that it *can* represent is `1`.

I suggest you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you need this level of precision, consider the [Decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html)

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.0)-decimal.Decimal('1.0e-17')
Decimal('0.999999999999999990')
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.0)-decimal.Decimal('1.0e-17')<decimal.Decimal(1.0)
True
```

And:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(1.0)-decimal.Decimal('1.0e-17')<1.0
True
```

Careful with the last one though because you can get conversion errors.

Others have suggested [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and I also recommend [Don’t Store That in a Float](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/02/05/dont-store-that-in-a-float/)

Answer (score 2):

you can handle those. note that

```
>>> 1.e-17 == 0
False
```

and

```
>>> 1.e-17 + 1.e-18
1.1e-17
```

you simply cannot handle 1-1e-17, because the mantissa won't fit in the finite precision

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('1')-Decimal(str(10**-17)) < Decimal('1')
True
```

Use the [decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html), for that kind of accuracy!

Answer (score 0):

You have `epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16` so it is normal that `(1. - (1.e-17) ) = 1` because `1.e-17 < epsilon`.