# Python how to handle very small numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am comparing numbers from 2 dictionaries (total comparisons ~ 1M). Here is a code snippet:

```
for i in dict1:
    val1 = dict[i]
    val2 = dict2[i]

    if (val1 != 0.000):
        perctg_diff = (val1 - val2)/val1 * 100
        if perctg_diff > 3.0:
            dict3.update({i:(val1,val2,perctg_diff)})
    if (val2 !=0.000):
        perctg_diff = (val2 - val1)/val2 * 100
        if perctg_diff > 3.0:
            dict3.update({i:(val1,val2,perctg_diff)})
```

I am finding percentage difference and writing the difference when more than 3% in `dict3`. After execution of script, I found some of the numbers in `dict3` are

```
(1052712, (2.88541545330242e-33, 2.3194405728563e-27, 99.9998755986471))
(1052713, (8.1367737331018e-34, 7.83224080670401e-31, 99.8961118033279))
(1052715, (1.79168848952333e-33, 6.71766997709614e-31, 99.733287211841))
(1052717, (1.03397638198887e-25, 4.49948480152819e-26, 56.4836791255002))
(1400879, (0.0, 1.39114642689358e-36, 100.0))
(1290291, (0.0, 1.89369462623834e-20, 100.0))
```

What is effective/efficient way I can get rid of the numerical roundoff and ignore the comparison when numbers are these small?

(Using python 2.7 with numpy)

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to numpy?

Comment: Maybe [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the numbers?

Comment: i don't understand but may be `decimal` module in python or `numpy.nextafter()` can help.

Comment: I found this may be it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555659/python-arithmetic-with-small-numbers

Comment: What do you mean by "small"? These percentage differences are correct, there is no numerical roundoff. (The difference in the exponents is 2 or more, so it is more than 100 times smaller, so the percentage difference is greater than 99%.)

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) is close (pun intended) to what you want. I evaluates
the formula:

> > > absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))

So you could use that to filter your data, with `atol` the smallest absolute difference you want to still consider and `rtol` set at 3%.