# Can't get numpy to add long doubles

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have a long double in some python code,

```
In [51]: psr[0]['F0'].val
Out[51]: 205.53069608827314596
```

I want to set this to a different value, which is also a long double:

```
In [52]: newparam
Out[52]: 205.53069608827315375
```

I can add large numbers to the first quantity, eg:

```
In [53]: psr[0]['F0'].val = psr[0]['F0'].val+1

In [55]: psr[0]['F0'].val
Out[55]: 206.53069608827314596
```

but i cant get it to take the value of new param:

```
In [50]: psr[0]['F0'].val=newparam

In [51]: psr[0]['F0'].val
Out[51]: 205.53069608827314596
```

If i look to see what the 'nextafter' is:

```
In [61]: np.nextafter(psr[0]['F0'].val, 300)
Out[61]: 205.53069608827314597
```

So i dont understand why i can't get it to take the value of newparam.. I've got C code that does this, so i'm sure Python must be able to aswell.

Answer (score 2):

It seems alright to me.
don't think you quite understand the purpose of nextafter(), here is the doc:

> nextafter(x1, x2[, out])
>
> Return the next representable floating-point value after x1 in the
>   direction of x2 element-wise.

usage:
[Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount)

Comment: Well, i had read the doc on nextafter, which given that the next representable value is a much smaller difference than the change in value im trying to achieve (ie, eps < (val-newval)), is exactly why im confused as to why it wont accept the new value

Comment: maybe python treat 205.53069608827314596 and 205.53069608827315375 as the same thing in memory. try: `a = 205.53069608827314596` `b = 205.53069608827315375` `print a==b`

Comment: In [8]: a = np.longdouble(205.53069608827314596)

    In [9]: b = np.longdouble(205.53069608827315375)

    In [10]: a
    Out[10]: 205.53069608827314596

    In [11]: b
    Out[11]: 205.53069608827314596

Comment: so apparently it just cant tell the difference.. but i dont understand why my C code can then.. its running on the same system.