# Smallest positive float64 number

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find a `numpy.float64` value that is as close to zero as possible.

Numpy offers several constants that allow to do something similar:

- `np.finfo(np.float64).eps = 2.2204460492503131e-16`
- `np.finfo(np.float64).tiny = 2.2250738585072014e-308`

These are both reasonably small, but when I do this

```
>>> x = np.finfo(np.float64).tiny
>>> x / 2
6.9533558078350043e-310
```

the result is even smaller. When using an impromptu binary search I can get down to about `1e-323`, before the value is rounded down to `0.0`.

Is there a constant for this in numpy that I am missing? Alternatively, is there a *right* way to do this?

Comment: Use np.nextafter. Almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. If you write this as an answer I will gladly accept it. I agree that the topic of the question you linked is similar, but I would have never thought about looking for those keyword with my problem.

Comment: May I ask why you need this? Just to make sure you're not trapped by an XY problem:)

Comment: Primarily out of curiosity. A coworker asked me if I know how to do this and I couldn't come up with a better answer than "Let's ask this on SO". I don't know his precise application though.

Comment: FYI: The floating point values between 0 and `np.finfo(np.float64).tiny` are known as "denormal" or "subnormal" numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: Not to be confused with "abnormal" numbers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `np.nextafter`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nextafter(0, 1)
4.9406564584124654e-324
>>> np.nextafter(np.float32(0), np.float32(1))
1.4012985e-45
```

Comment: this function gave me zero, why ?

Comment: @Feras, I'm a bit late to the party, but that's an indication that FTZ bit is set in your FPU. Can happen when e.g. loading a shared object which was compiled with "fast math" enabled.

Answer (score 0):

2^-1075 is the smallest positive float.
2^-1075 = 5.10^-324