# Cannot use interp1d because of rounding error

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to stretch mesh points using density functions. For example, given the following point distribtion (uniformally distributed):

[image]

The code below will change the distribution to something like this:
[image]

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import erf

# the x interval limits
a = 0.0
b = 3.0

# The density function, normalize it
_density_func = lambda x: 5*x
density_func = lambda x: _density_func(x) / quad(_density_func, a, b)[0]*(b-a)

# The xarr and yarr
Npts = 50
xarr = np.linspace(a, b, Npts)
yarr = np.zeros_like(xarr)

# Calculate the primitive function F = integral of density_func, from a, to t normalized by the int(density_func, a, b)
# F = np.vectorize(lambda t: quad(density_func, a, t)[0] / quad(density_func, a, b)[0])
F = np.vectorize(lambda t: quad(density_func, a, t)[0])

# if debug is true, print some info
debug = True
if debug:
    print('The range of xarr is: [', a, b, ']')
    print('The range of F(xarr) is: [', F(xarr).min(), F(xarr).max(), ']')

# Calculate the new x distribution of points using the inverse function of F.
# Use the trick of interpolation to calculate the inverse function,i.e: interp1d(y, x)(x)
xnew = interp1d(F(xarr), xarr)(xarr) 

# plot the result
plt.scatter(xnew, yarr, facecolors='none', edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```

When I run this script, I get the following error:

```
The range of xarr is: [ 0.0 3.0 ]
The range of F(xarr) is: [ 0.0 2.9999999999999996 ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meshDensity.py", line 38, in <module>
    xnew = interp1d(F(xarr), xarr)(xarr)
  File "C:\Users\navaro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py", line 79, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)
  File "C:\Users\navaro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 664, in _evaluate
    below_bounds, above_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
  File "C:\Users\navaro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 696, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is above the interpolation "
ValueError: A value in x_new is above the interpolation range.
```

As you can see, the problem is the right limit of `F(xarr)` is `2.9999999999999996` instead of the exact value `3.0`.

Could you please suggest any solution to this rounding error problem?
I appreciate any help.

**Edit**: a temporary solution is to use `mpmath.quad` function with `mpmath.mp.dps = 20` but this makes the script relatively slow.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is inherent to using floating point numbers on a computer: you have to cut off the decimals somewhere

As you can see, the error is 4.440892098500626e-16, which is probably around the floating point accuracy on your system

The mathematical approach is probably correct, but I would suggest handling this through software, i.e. do you really need 16 decimal places? If you put a couple `round(num,6)` in there, you would make your code more robust to these kinds of issues

More specifically, your code runs if I replace your density func with:

`density_func = lambda x: round(_density_func(x) / quad(_density_func, a, b)[0]*(b-a),6)`

EDIT:
funnily enough, I ran into the same issue just now:
3.0-2.9999999999999996 = 4.440892098500626e-16

where we both know that it should have been 0.0000000000000004

Funky things happen when you're dealing with numbers at the edge of your floating point accuracy

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. unfortunately I couldn't understand how could this solve the problem.

Comment: `round` is not a panacea, because the rounded value may still not be perfectly representable in binary. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician I updated the post to mark the place where the rounding would go and now it runs on my computer. But take a minute to understand what's going on because this kind of issue is pretty common

Comment: @imochoa: Sorry, I don't think this is a solution because my script is a part of a larger program that needs to deal with meshes with high precision.

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician well the sad truth is that floating point operations are not exact, your accuracy is going to be limited by the datatype you're using (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477908/smallest-positive-float64-number) so, you can take 10 decimal places instead of 6 but if you're dealing with smaller numbers than that.... consider changing units, working on log scale or something a long those lines

Comment: @imochoa: I will use `mpmath.quad` instead of `scipy.integrate.quad`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using arbitrary precision arithmetics module, `mpmath`.

```py
import numpy as np
import mpmath as mp
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mp.mp.dps = 18
# the x interval limits
a = 0.0
b = 3.0

# The density function, normalize it
_density_func = lambda x: 5*x
density_func = lambda x: _density_func(x) / mp.quad(_density_func, [a, b])*(b-a)

# The xarr and yarr
Npts = 50
xarr = np.linspace(a, b, Npts)
yarr = np.zeros_like(xarr)

# Calculate the primitive function F = integral of density_func, from a, to t.
F = np.vectorize(lambda t: mp.quad(density_func, [a, t]))

# if debug is true, print some info
debug = True
if debug:
    print('The range of xarr is: [', a, b, ']')
    print('The range of F(xarr) is: [', F(xarr).min(), F(xarr).max(), ']')

# Calculate the new x distribution of points using the inverse function of F.
# Use the trick of interpolation to calculate the inverse function,i.e: interp1d(y, x)(x)
xnew = interp1d(F(xarr), xarr)(xarr) 

# plot the result
plt.scatter(xnew, yarr, facecolors='none', edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```

After running the script, I get:

```
The range of xarr is: [ 0.0 3.0 ]
The range of F(xarr) is: [ 0.0 3.0 ]
```

[image]