# Unusual python division results

Tags: python

I entered the following code into the python Shell:

```
>>>1/10**323
1e-323
>>>1/10**324
0.0
```

As you can see the result is unexpected.
Does anybody know why this happens or how to change this?
Furthermore, I also got this error:

```
>>> 1/10**323.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    1/10**323.1
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: `1/10**323.1` is too large to be stored in double precision float. You could try the `decimal` library to set an arbitrary precision value for the output.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477908/smallest-positive-float64-number

Comment: "As you can see the result is unexpected" Is it? What result do you expect? Why?

Answer (score 2):

Those problems stem directly from floating point numbers, and more precisely from [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), which is the standard implemented in most commonly used hardware and most software uses.

Python `float` is a double precision IEEE 754 floating point number type, which means that it stores all numbers of type `float` using exactly 8 bytes, which is 64 bits. 1 bit is used to store if the number is positive or negative, 11 bits are used for the exponent (the part after the `e` in scientific notation), and 53 bits are used for significand (the part before the `e`).

The real value of `1/10**324` is so close to zero that a 64 bit floating point cannot represent it. There's almost always some error in making floating point calculations, which is unavoidable, but when you're so close to zero it's much more noticeable!

That error is not because of the division. You'd get the same error with `10**323.1` or even `10**323.0`.

Python integers are variable sized, you can make larger and larger numbers which take up more and more bytes to store. This means that integer operations (like `10**324`) don't overflow. But if you use `int ** float`, the result likely won't be an integer number, so you'll have to store it in a float. And exponentiation of large numbers easily gets you to a number that doesn't fit in 64 bits any more. What do you do? Well, there are two options:

1. Use the largest possible value, which gets labelled `Infinity` in the standard. This is what JavaScript does.
2. Be cautious and prevent the programmer from making mistakes. What mistakes? Well, `10 ** 500 / 10 ** 499` should be `10` but if `10 ** 500` evaluates to `Infinity` and so does `10 ** 499`, you'll end up with `Infinity / Infinity` which is indeterminate and can either error or give a special answer (called `NaN` for "not a number"), but you're not gonna get your `10` back.

In Python 2, `int / int` used to be what now is `int // int`, which means that `5 / 2` used to be `2`. In Python 3, this was corrected. The result of division is so often not an integer in practice, that it made more sense to treat it just like `float / float`. As a side effect, `4 / 2` is now `2.0` instead of `2`.