# Why is this program always returning 326 as a value for d

Tags: python

It doesn't matter what number I enter, d variable is somehow always 326,
please help I'm a beginner.

```
a=int(input("enter a number:"))
c=0
d=0
while a>0:

    b=a%10
    a=a/10
    
    if b%2==0:
        c=c+1
    
    else:
        d=d+1

print("even numbers:",c)
print("odd numbers:",d)
```

This is pretty much it

Comment: What do you want this program to do?

Comment: It's supposed to say how many even and odd digits there are in a number when it is entered

Answer (score 1):

You should use int division: `a=a//10`. Otherwise it will loop until Python can't tell the difference between a=0.00000.... and 0. which is approximately 326 digits.

Note that if you input 10000 you get 324 as output

Edit: I found in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38481260/13525512) the smallest positive float you can get:

```
np.nextafter(0, 1)
4.9406564584124654e-324
```

Which confirms my first interpretation.

In the comments, @Joshua also pointed out the differences between Python 2 and 3 regarding division.

Comment: Note that this is a critical difference between Python3 and Python2 -- Python2 treats the `\\` operator as integer division, where Python3 treats it as real division, and coerces (yay dynamic typing!) the operators to real numbers (from integers) as needed.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp you mean `/`