# How to add to/subtract from float value the smallest possible value in pure python [explained how is different]?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question is **only for Python programmers**. This question is **not duplicate not working** [Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount) see explanation bottom.

---

I want to add/subtract for any float some smallest values which will change this float value about one bit of [mantissa/significant part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). How to calculate such small number efficiently in **pure Python**.

For example I have such array of x:

```
xs = [1e300, 1e0, 1e-300]
```

What will be function for it to generate **the smallest value**? All assertion should be valid.

```
for x in xs:
  assert x < x + smallestChange(x)
  assert x > x - smallestChange(x)
```

Consider that `1e308 + 1 == 1e308` since `1` does means `0` for mantissa so `smallestChange' should be dynamic.

Pure Python solution will be the best.

---

**Why this is not duplicate of [Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount)** - two simple tests prove it with invalid results.

(1) The question is not aswered in [Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount) difference:

**[Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount) just not works try this code**:

```
import math
epsilon  = math.ldexp(1.0, -53) # smallest double that 0.5+epsilon != 0.5
maxDouble = float(2**1024 - 2**971)  # From the IEEE 754 standard
minDouble  = math.ldexp(1.0, -1022) # min positive normalized double
smallEpsilon  = math.ldexp(1.0, -1074) # smallest increment for doubles < minFloat
infinity = math.ldexp(1.0, 1023) * 2

def nextafter(x,y):    
    """returns the next IEEE double after x in the direction of y if possible"""
    if y==x:
       return y         #if x==y, no increment

    # handle NaN
    if x!=x or y!=y:
        return x + y       

    if x >= infinity:
        return infinity

    if x <= -infinity:
        return -infinity

    if -minDouble < x < minDouble:
        if y > x:
            return x + smallEpsilon
        else:
            return x - smallEpsilon  

    m, e = math.frexp(x)        
    if y > x:
        m += epsilon
    else:
        m -= epsilon

    return math.ldexp(m,e)  
print nextafter(0.0, -1.0), 'nextafter(0.0, -1.0)'
print nextafter(-1.0, 0.0), 'nextafter(-1.0, 0.0)'
```

Results of [Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount) is invalid:

```
>>> nextafter(0.0, -1)
0.0
```

Should be nonzero.

```
>>> nextafter(-1,0)
-0.9999999999999998
```

Should be '-0.9999999999999999'.

(2) It was not asked how to add/substract the smallest value but was asked how to add/substract value in specific direction - propose solution is need to know x and y. Here is required to know only x.

(3) Propose solution in [Increment a python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount) will not work on border conditions.

Comment: If you care about this, you're probably working in an area where numpy would be very helpful. Does `numpy.nextafter` work for you? You can use `numpy.nextafter(x, numpy.inf)` to always go towards positive.

Comment: I not want use numpy to reduce memory footprint but maybe need study numpy code to extract small function. I prefer use simple python modules.

Comment: Reduce memory footprint? NumPy only takes about 8 MB to import on my machine. What kind of program are you writing?

Comment: Sure for simple PC it is not matter I will use GAE some additional +8Mb will cost and load time will be longer - it is different scale you can not know this :) If I will be use PC I will not care as you ...

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> (1.0).hex()
'0x1.0000000000000p+0'
>>> float.fromhex('0x0.0000000000001p+0')
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> 1.0 + float.fromhex('0x0.0000000000001p+0')
1.0000000000000002
>>> (1.0 + float.fromhex('0x0.0000000000001p+0')).hex()
'0x1.0000000000001p+0'
```

Just use the same sign and exponent.

Comment: You approach is good. I found something much faster with use `sys` and `math` without string conversions using `frexp` and `ldexp` and `sys.float_info.mant_dig`.

Comment: I do some test but not finished code and result from timeit is `hex about 85.5520534034` and `frexp 19.9034547687` before optimization and tests.

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Dickinson's answer to a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10426033/49793) fares much better, but still fails to give the correct results for the parameters `(0, 1)`.

This is probably a good starting point for a pure Python solution. However, getting this exactly right in all cases is not easy, as there are many corner cases. So you should have a really good unit test suite to cover all corner cases.

Whenever possible, you should consider using one of the solutions that are based on the well-tested C runtime function instead (i.e. via `ctypes` or `numpy`).

You mentioned somewhere that you are concerned about the memory overhead of `numpy`. However, the effect of this one function on your working set shout be very small, certainly not several Megabytes (that might be virtual memory or private bytes.)

Comment: First of all `1e16` too small for `1e308` it will be not visible. Why mantissa is `53 bits`, exponent is `10 bits` so it is `1024 in base2` so the smallest value is `0x1p971`. Check this `(float.fromhex('0x1.1ccf385ebc8a0p+1023') - float.fromhex('0x1.1ccf385ebc89fp+1023')).hex()` in decimal notation  `1.99584030953472e+292`. The smallest mantissa change depends can be  53 bits `2.220446049250313e-16` (if first bit set to 1).

Comment: Simple example of bug: `-0x1.ffffffffffffep-1 -0x1.0000000000000p+0 nextafter(-1.0, 0.0)`. Why compare `float.fromhex('-0x1.ffffffffffffep-1') float.fromhex('-0x1.fffffffffffffp-1') float.fromhex('-0x1.0000000000000p+0')` - value between `float.fromhex('-0x1.ffffffffffffep-1')` and `float.fromhex('-0x1.0000000000000p+0')` is `float.fromhex('-0x1.fffffffffffffp-1')`.

Comment: So for which input do you get wrong results? Show the actual result *and* the expected result.

Comment: for example first one `-0x1.ffffffffffffep-1 -0x1.0000000000000p+0 nextafter(-1.0, 0.0)` - should be `-0x1.fffffffffffffp-1`.

Comment: True, and the cause is easy to see. Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10426033/49793 This still doesn't handle 0 correctly.

Comment: Yes I read this but no recommend to use it. Struct pack is in my option too low level approach - it is false assumption that float has some fixed format - maybe I am wrong. I do own code with use `hex` and other with `ldexp` and `frexp`. It is much simpler and `hex` is working - no testedt `ldexp` and `frexp`. I uses also high level `sys` to understand float format.